# How to get the header and left column to stick together on page scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

OK, I have searched the web both far and wide and have yet to find the answer to my question.   I have found several that come close but none that have worked in the way i am wanting it to behave.

First some simple ground rules.

I am not looking for the solution that required the content of the Div to have the overflow setting enabled.  While there are several stackoverflow pages with that solution it does not provide what i am needing as all that will do is case my page to have two scroll bars.....one on the div and one on the page....for my work that will provide a negative User Experience.

If it becomes a must then JavaScript solutions might work but hoping for a pure CSS solution.

I am using , or at least attempting to use pure CSS with the modern "position: Sticky;" feature,

This seems to be very simple and straight forward and, for the most part works as expected......that is with one minor exception.

If i use only this

```
th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

It will freeze the entire header row once it reaches the top of the page.

If i do only this

```
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

It will freeze the first TD column and first TH column on the left as it scrolls.

So far in either case it works as expected.    However, if i use both of them at the same time I get only partial behavior.

It this case the left column (TD & TH) will freeze left as expected however the TH will freeze on the top all TH's with the exception of the First column TH which now scrolls.

I have made a [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3nm48pfj/10/)) to show the current behavior.   What i am trying to do is the lock that first TH to either top or left depending on the page scrolling.

Comment: Just to clarify: if a user scrolls over to the right, you want the first column of the table to "stick" to the left, but if they scroll down the page, you want the top row to "stick" to the top?

Comment: Correct.   Think in terms of freezing rows and columns in Microsoft Excel.   Trying to achieve that same type of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, took a few days break from this issue and finally decided to take another crack at it.   After some additional tweaking I was able to finally get it to work with pure CSS and no javaScript or DIV overflow enabling needed.

[Updated jsFiddle with solution](https://jsfiddle.net/3nm48pfj/13/)

I was able to tweak my CSS to the following which is freezing the left and headers correctly.

```
tr:nth-child(1)  th:nth-child(1) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;   /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

tr:nth-child(2)  th:nth-child(1n+1) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;   /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

tr:nth-child(2)  th:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

tr:nth-child(1n+1) td:nth-child(1) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;   /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}
```